# I am making a custom widget, how do I use it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a custom widget like code below

```
class FormHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  const FormHeader({required this.onPressed, Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return ElevatedButton(
       child: Text('click me'),
       onPressed: () async {
         try{
            print('first line');
            await this.onPressed();
            print('third line');
         }
         catch(e){
           Print('$e');
         }
       }
     );
  }
}


//in the main form

FormHeader(
  onPressed: () async{
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), ()=>throw Exception("second line"));
  }
)
```

please just copy paste this code in the test project and make it work to print first second and third in row!!!!

Comment: Please clarify the functionality you want!!

Comment: I want a custom widget just like code above, I have problem to use it

Comment: In your custom widget you can not make functionalities. Functionalities are to be made where the widget is to be used. The try..catch is to be implemented in when calling FormHeader. Not unless you elaborate what you realy want to do with the widget

Comment: ooh this is bad because I just have to use it only in the way I wrote :( without await I haven't any problem I can use it, but everything be messed up with await

Comment: The answer below will guide you. Change your  VoidCallBack typer to Function type

Answer (score 0):

From what I get this is somewhat you want!

Widget class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function onPressed;
  final bool outlineBtn;
  final bool isLoading;
  CustomBtn({this.text, this.onPressed, this.outlineBtn, this.isLoading});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _outlineBtn = outlineBtn ?? false;
    bool _isLoading = isLoading ?? false;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: Container(
        height: 65.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _outlineBtn ? Colors.transparent : Colors.black,
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 2.0,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
            12.0,
          ),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 24.0,
          vertical: 8.0,
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Visibility(
              visible: _isLoading ? false : true,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  text ?? "Text",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    color: _outlineBtn ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _isLoading,
              child: Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 30.0,
                  width: 30.0,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main Class

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {


  void _submitForm() async {
    // Set the form to loading state
    setState(() {
      _loginFormLoading = true;
    });

    // Run the create account method
    String _loginFeedback = await _loginAccount();

    // If the string is not null, we got error while create account.
    if(_loginFeedback != null) {
      _alertDialogBuilder(_loginFeedback);

      // Set the form to regular state [not loading].
      setState(() {
        _loginFormLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }







  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 24.0,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Welcome!\nLogin to your account",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: Constants.boldHeading,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
            
                  CustomBtn(
                    text: "Login",
                    onPressed: () {
                      _submitForm();
                    },
                    isLoading: _loginFormLoading,
                  )
                ],
              ),
          
               
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see the `async` is done in the main class level and that's where you create a void function/method and do whatever you want. Let the widget class be only a container for the functionality.

Comment: yeah i want something like the code you wrote but the important thing is, I'm looking for a way to manage isLoading inside the custom widget not in main form!!! because I want to use it, in the stateless widget without any other codes like streams or any other state management solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef FutureCallback<T> = FutureOr<T> Function();

class Formheader extends StatelessWidget {
  const Formheader({Key? key, required this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);
  final FutureCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        try {
          debugPrint('first line');
          await onPressed();
          // debugPrint('third line');
        } catch (e) {
          debugPrint('$e');
        }

        debugPrint('third line');
      },
      child: const Text('Click me'),
    );
  }
}
```